# I want to change background-color and text color inside <a> tag during hovering using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with home, aboutme, contact inline enclosed inside `<li>` and `<a>` tag. The background is set to black and text color to white. Now when hovering over the text I want to change the background color to white and text to black using CSS. How can I do in css.

```
#navbar {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#navbar ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#navbar li {
    display: inline;
}

#navbar a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

a {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Kindly share code to see what you attempted

Comment: 1) show your code. 2) use `:hover`

Comment: you need css `hover`.PLease google you will get tons of examples

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: This is so very basic, that IMHO it should not even be asked here. Please go read a tutorial on CSS basics instead.

Comment: This is what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Comment: i am impressed by people wasting 15min or more to write question instead of googling for 5 seconds and get the code within 2 min and have a workinng example within 5 min

Comment: @TemaniAfif A surprising amount of people cannot express the problem they are having in few enough words to google it

Comment: @Luca yes but now Google are in our life and in our mind !! :p simply think and you get the result ;)

Comment: @Pete Thank you..Your link helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that will help you. You must add pseudo-class(:hover) for parent(li) and child(a) at the same time.

```css
li{
  //This sets the default background color of the li item.
  background-color: #000000;
}
li a{
  //This sets the default text color of an anchor (a-tag) in a list item.
  color: #ffffff;
}
li:hover{ //Using pseudo-element hover
  //When hovering over a list item, we set the background to white.
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
li a:hover{
  //And on hovering over the anchor in a list item, we set the text color of the anchor to white
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Abot me</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

See this link for more information about pseudo-elements and how to use them:
[CSS Pseudo-classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Comment: Could you please add an explanation so the op know where they are going wrong.